# Не работает proxy в React (http-proxy-middleware)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tomcat, proxy, http-status-code-404

При запуске приложения react, не удается выполнить проксирование запросов. Настройку proxy выполняю через файл setupProxy.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();


/* Change proxy here */
const target = 'http://localhost:8080';

app.use(
  proxy('/api', {
  target,
  changeOrigin: true
}),
proxy('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:1200/#/', changeOrigin: true,
}),
);
app.listen(1234);
```

Часть файла package.json: 
`"scripts": {
    "develop": "concurrently -r \"npm:type-check:watch\" \"npm:start\"",
    "start": "parcel ./src/index.html --host=0.0.0.0 --port=1200 & node src/setupProxy.js",
    "start-l": "parcel ./src/index.html --port=1200",
    "server": "node src/setupProxy.js",
    "build": "npm run type-check && parcel build ./src/index.html --public-url '/'",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "type-check:watch": "tsc --noEmit --watch"
  }`
Для сборки пробовал запускать команды `yarn install`, `yarn build`, `npm install`, `yarn run`. 
Запускал командой `yarn start-l`, а также `yarn start-l server`, проект запускается, 
но в консоли выводится ошибка 404. Прилагаю скрины
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа чужая, поэтому код должен быть рабочим, проблема скорее всего в проксировании. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что на компьютере Ubuntu был закрыт порт 1234. Его удалось открыть, выполнив следующую команду в терминале: 
`$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

```js
proxy: {
  ...proxy,
  '/api': {
    tagret: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
  }
}
```